# Firebase Sign in Method

Tags: firebase-authentication

Sorry this might be a stupid question but I cant find out a solution to this anywhere. We are using the firebase database for a class project and I was trying to use there authentication system but I can't seem to figure out how to enable it. Everywhere I look you are suppose to click the edit pencil picture next to the sign in method and that should pop up with an option to enable it but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there any thing else you are suppose to do first that I might have missed.[Sign in methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxc9o.png)

Thanks

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) you can follow:

You need to first create a Firebase project and then add an app in the project. 
You can enable the sign in method by doing:

a.In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.

b.On the Sign in method tab, enable the whatever sign-in method you need and click Save.